# Implementing a game menu in a Swift Sprite-Kit game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, ios9

I have created a platformer game, and I when I start the game, it goes straight into playing. I would like to have a menu that has a button to start the game and a button which would lead to a shop, to purchase different backgrounds or characters with in game currency that has been earned. I would appreciate it if someone could help me to implement this kind of menu. It would also be great if I could get help on how to pause the game while playing.

Comment: What you already done? You could use `SKScene` for menu and layout your buttons there. Current question doesn't show any effort from you.

Comment: I have created the whole game already, just looking for some tips on how to create the menu. To be specific, I don't understand how I would be able to create a starting page before the game when the app opens, which leads to the game starting when a button is pressed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create scene for menu. When user push start button you present your game scene.

```
class MenuScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        addButtons()
    }

    private func addButtons() {
        // TODO layout buttons here
    }

    private func startGame() {
        let gameScene = GameScene(size: view!.bounds.size)
        let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.15)
        view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
    }
}
```

And present it from your controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sceneView = view as! SKView
    // sceneView.showsFPS = true
    // sceneView.showsNodeCount = true
    sceneView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    scene = MenuScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    sceneView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is my first game so i'm still learning of course.   worked perfectly. Now I just need to try to get buttons on here.

Comment: Ok so I put a button that successfully leads to the GameScene.swift file where my game is in, but my game is way too much zoomed in. Any tips on how to fix that?

Comment: Better to start new question with screenshot.